# Reading a some specific line from a text file using GUI

Tags: java

Hi I have encounted an error. Im currently using Eclipse mars and its windowbuilder to browse up a text file and then read it and pick up some parts of it and display it. The text file looks likes this.

```
90 hello world
90 sunny day
89 mercedes benz
```

My code:

```
package ecu;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 

public class file {
JFileChooser fc= new JFileChooser();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public void PickMe() throws Exception{
if(fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    try {


    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fc.getSelectedFile()));
    try{



     String readBuff = buff.readLine();
     String section = "";
    while (buff!=null){
        if(readBuff.equals("90")){

            sb.append(readBuff);
        }
                    buff.readLine();
    }
    }
    finally {
        buff.close();
    }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

else {
    sb.append("file not choosen");
}


    }






    }
```

So, i would like that anything that stands after 90 to be written out. the GUI code looks like this:

```
package ecu;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.FileChooserUI;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class exjobb {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                exjobb window = new exjobb();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public exjobb() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBounds(27, 11, 359, 142);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);

    JButton browse = new JButton("Browse");
    browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            file of = new file();
            try{
                of.PickMe();
                }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textArea.setText(of.sb.toString());
        }
    });
    browse.setBounds(27, 191, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(browse);


}
    }
```

I have a text area drawn out and i would like the text that i've sorted out to be displayed there. Then i run this program, it doesn't work. I appriciate all the help i can get!

Comment: readLine() reads a line. So it will contain "90 hello world". And "90 hello world" is not equal to "90". Look at the String javadoc to find a method that would tell if a string starts with "90". Also, learn to use your debugger. It's not really hard, and will save you tons of hours. You should be able to diagnose such bugs by yourself.

Comment: if(readBuff.startsWith("90"))

Comment: im very new to java, how do i use debugger? @JBNizet

Comment: @stepanian i tried to use it but it didn't work

Comment: @AdnanHossain do you use an IDE to write and compile your code? Eclipse? IntelliJ? NetBeans? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/debugging.html?origin=old_help, https://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html. They all work basically the same way.